# How to write UNICODE or Extended ASCII with WriteConsoleOutput

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, console, g++

When using only ASCII characters, all characters and given color values are displayed correctly, however,  whenever i use Extended ASCII or UNICODE characters i get this error message (and my g++ compiler indicates the problem is the non-ASCII character):

```
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
error: narrowing conversion of '14849683' from 'int' to 'WCHAR' {aka 'wchar_t'} inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

I am using the `-lgdi32` parameter in my compile command.

Whether I use `WriteConsoleOutputA` or `WriteConsoleOutputW` appears to make no difference at all.

I believe the CHAR_INFO array character width is 8bit by default so I think this should be changed but I cannot find anything about it in the Windows Console API docs.

So to be clear, all the # characters appear correct, but if i use characters like: ░ or ┐ I get the above error message.

```cpp
CHAR_INFO map[400] = {
            '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C,'#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C,
            '#', 0x002C, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', 0x002C,
            '#', 0x002C, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', 0x002C,
            '#', 0x002C, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', 0x002C,
            '#', 0x002C, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', 0x002C,
            '#', 0x002C, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', 0x002C,
            '#', 0x002C, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', 0x002C,
            '#', 0x002C, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', 0x002C,
            '#', 0x002C, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', 0x002C,
            '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C,'#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C, '#', 0x002C
        };


        COORD coordinateBufferSize;
        coordinateBufferSize.Y = 10;
        coordinateBufferSize.X = 10;

        COORD topLeftCoordinate;
        topLeftCoordinate.Y = 0;
        topLeftCoordinate.X = 0;

        PSMALL_RECT srcWriteRect;
        srcWriteRect->Top = 10;         // Number of rows to the top
        srcWriteRect->Left = 10;        // Numbers of columns to the side
        srcWriteRect->Bottom = 19;
        srcWriteRect->Right = 19;


        HANDLE oldScreenBuffer, newScreenBuffer;


        oldScreenBuffer = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        newScreenBuffer = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            NULL,
            CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
            NULL);

        BOOL succes = WriteConsoleOutputA(
            newScreenBuffer,                    // The new ScreenBuffer
            map,                                // The char array we want to display
            coordinateBufferSize,               // 
            topLeftCoordinate,
            srcWriteRect
        );

        SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(newScreenBuffer);
```

Comment: You're initializing the `UnicodeChar` field with a UTF-8 encoded literal. For example, "▓" is stored in a UTF-8 source file as "\xe2\x96\x93". The compiler sees this as the 32-bit int constant 0xe29693 (i.e. `'14849683'`) and implicitly truncates it as the 16-bit `wchar_t` value 0x9693 (i.e. Unicode "隓"). You should use a wide-character literal, e.g. `L'▓'`. In this case the compiler decodes UTF-8 "\xe2\x96\x93" as the Unicode ordinal 0x2593.

Comment: Note that the `UnicodeChar` field is limited to characters in the 16-bit basic multilingual plane (BMP). Characters in supplementary Unicode planes (e.g. most emojis) require a pair of `CHAR_INFO` records, with the character encoded as a UTF-16 surrogate pair. UTF-16 surrogate pairs won't render properly in the classic console (conhost.exe), but the user should be able to copy and paste them into another window such as notepad.

Comment: Also, it should go without saying that you must use `WriteConsoleOutputW` when the `CHAR_INFO` array is initialized with Unicode ordinals. That's the default since `UnicodeChar` is the first member of the union, for which you need to initialize with wide-character literals.

Comment: I hope that one day i will posses such deep knowledge as you do my friend. Thank you for elaborating and giving me insight into the problem instead of just giving a 'quick fix' answer. Could you please combine your comments in an answer so i can accept it as the correct one? Thanks again!

Comment: @ErykSun could you add your'e comment as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `WriteConsoleOutputW`. The CHAR_INFO type is a struct of attribute (color in your case) and a union of character and wide character, so no problem here.

Some console fonts don't support many characters, check if your default font supports the characters you want to print.